# Windows Batch - Insert text mid file and copy to different location

Tags: windows, batch-file

As part of a project I need to add text in the middle of many eml files using batch scripting.

I am able to add the text successfully for the files that are 3kb to 50kb with the below mentioned code, but recently the file sizes where coming around 95,000kb and my script stopped working.

```bat
if %count% NEQ %nullCount% (
FOR %%f in ("%SYMPHONY_UNZIP_DIRECTORY%\*.eml") do (
  Echo processing %%f eml file
  Echo %date% %Time% processing %%f eml file >> %SYMPHONY_LOG_FILE%     
   (FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ %%f"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    if "!var:~0,10!" == "x-globalre" (   
    Echo X-AUTONOMY-SUBTYPE: Symphony
     ) 
    Echo(!var!
     ENDLOCAL
     )) >> "%SYMPHONY_EML_PROCESSED_DIRECTORY%\%%~nxf"
)
```

Below is the sample input file the file size is around 96,000kb …and for this I am not able to insert the text `X-AUTONOMY-SUBTYPE: Symphony` above `x-globalrelay-MsgType` which is the requirement.

With file sizes of around 9kb-20kb I am able to do it. But for 95,000kb I am not able to do it.

```html
Date: Tue, 3 Oct 2017 08:00:47 +0000 (UTC)
From: xyz
To:  abc
Message-ID: <2118122420.28271.1507075383746.JavaMail.tomcat@HKLVATAPP075>
Subject: Symphony: 2 users, 15 messages, duration 00:15
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_28270_1969329481.1507075372811"
x-globalrelay-MsgType: SymphonyIM
x-symphony-StreamType: SymphonyIM
x-symphony-StreamID: csvi8iOjIYQ9GXj3XelZqX///qUkjhEudA==
x-symphony-stream-partition: 1
x-symphony-ContentStartDateUTC: 1507016699478
x-symphony-ContentStopDateUTC: 1507017647347
x-symphony-FileGeneratedDateUTC: 1507075372810

------=_Part_28270_1969329481.1507075372811
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p><font color=3D"grey">Message ID: ZUGIzXyaMnvy=
----
----
-----
</html>
---------
```

Comment: Use a tool or scripting language which is better suited to the task. That said, for a batch file I would probably determine which if any line begins with `x-globalrelay-MsgType:` note it's line number and output all lines up to that into the new file. Next I would append `X-AUTONOMY-SUBTYPE: Symphony` and then all the lines from the noted line number onwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to do what I suggested in my comment to your question:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "SYMPHONY_UNZIP_DIRECTORY=F:\EmlProcessor\UnZipped"
Set "SYMPHONY_EML_PROCESSED_DIRECTORY=F:\EmlProcessor\Processed"
If /I Not "%CD%"=="%SYMPHONY_UNZIP_DIRECTORY%" (Set "_=T"
    PushD "%SYMPHONY_UNZIP_DIRECTORY%" 2>Nul||Exit/B)
If Not Exist "%SYMPHONY_EML_PROCESSED_DIRECTORY%\" Exit/B
If Not Exist *.eml Exit/B
Set "emlfile="
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=:" %%A In (
    'FindStr/NIBL "x-globalrelay-MsgType:" *.eml') Do (Set/A count=-1+%%B
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    <"%%A" (For /L %%C In (1,1,!count!) Do (Set "line="
            Set/P "line="
            Echo(!line!)
        Echo(X-AUTONOMY-SUBTYPE: Symphony
        More +!count!
        EndLocal)>"%SYMPHONY_EML_PROCESSED_DIRECTORY%\%%~nxA")
If "%_%"=="T" PopD
```

Notes:

- If your `.eml` files contain tabs on any line from the search string
  line onwards they will be changed to spaces.
- This will be unlikely to
  work if the file sizes exceed 64k lines.
- You may remove the `@Echo Off` line if echoing has already been turned off in the portion of the script not revealed in your question.

Comment: Thanks Compo But my file sizes are in the range of 90K,So you mean this code won't work.I have even tried with powershell but still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: I said 64k lines, _(64000)_, only you know the file sizes, did you try it? _I have a feeling that the `More` command will pause for a key press at around that many lines_

Comment: Hi Compo tried your code by substituting the following changes,i am very new to batch scripting so please excuse for any wrong doing.I pasted the code above

Comment: I have updated my code to supplement your specific paths, it requires no alterations, just run it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

 
If /I Not "%CD%"=="F:\EmlProcessor\UnZipped\" (Set "_=T"
    PushD "F:\EmlProcessor\UnZipped\" 2>Nul||Exit/B)
If Not Exist "F:\EmlProcessor\Processed\" Exit/B
If Not Exist *.eml Exit/B
Set "emlfile="
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=:" %%A In (
    'FindStr/NIBL "x-globalrelay-MsgType:" *.eml') Do (Set/A count=-1+%%B
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    <"%%A" (For /L %%C In (1,1,!count!) Do (Set "line="
            Set/P "line="
            Echo(!line!)
        Echo(X-AUTONOMY-SUBTYPE: Symphony
        More +!count!
        EndLocal)>"%SYMPHONY_EML_PROCESSED_DIRECTORY%\%%~nxA")
If "%_%"=="T" PopD
```

The code got struck and its not processing as with my previous code.I tried the file with around 70kb.As said i am new to batch scripting so please excuse me for any mistakes

Comment: A directory name should not end with a back slash, after all you will have almost certainly seen a message telling you that you cannot use one in a name when mistyping in the Windows GUI.

Comment: I also provided my code to be bolted onto the part of the script you failed to show me in your question. They were your variables, you'd already shown them, why have you overwritten with strings? My code didn't require any changes, you had the option to remove the first line only.